Mouse cursor weird after apt update. Wayland
Ubuntu Noble. All was fine until today, after apt update cursor starts lagging, but if you press the left mouse key on desktop, it fixes until you stop holding it. Also Mozilla got something weird going on - it shows its default cursor, but if you drag the window, it becomes my cursor again until I stop dragging the window (screens attached).
Here is my update log:
[
Start-Date: 2024-06-26 09:55:25
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.112'
Install: linux-tools-6.8.0-36-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-36.36, automatic), nvidia-dkms-470:amd64 (470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1, automatic), linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-36-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-36.36, automatic), linux-headers-6.8.0-36-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-36.36, automatic), linux-tools-6.8.0-36:amd64 (6.8.0-36.36, automatic), linux-modules-6.8.0-36-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-36.36, automatic), linux-image-6.8.0-36-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-36.36, automatic), linux-headers-6.8.0-36:amd64 (6.8.0-36.36, automatic)
Upgrade: libnvidia-common-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), linux-tools-common:amd64 (6.8.0-35.35, 6.8.0-36.36), libnvidia-fbc1-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), libnvidia-gl-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), libnvidia-gl-470:i386 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), linux-headers-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-35.35, 6.8.0-36.36), libnvidia-extra-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), nvidia-compute-utils-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), nvidia-driver-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), libnvidia-encode-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), nvidia-utils-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), xserver-xorg-video-nvidia-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), libnvidia-ifr1-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), libnvidia-decode-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), linux-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-35.35, 6.8.0-36.36), nvidia-kernel-common-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), linux-image-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-35.35, 6.8.0-36.36), libnvidia-cfg1-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), nvidia-kernel-source-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), libnvidia-compute-470:amd64 (470.239.06-0ubuntu2, 470.256.02-0ubuntu0.24.04.1), linux-libc-dev:amd64 (6.8.0-35.35, 6.8.0-36.36)
End-Date: 2024-06-26 10:00:28

Start-Date: 2024-06-26 10:32:01
Commandline: aptdaemon role='role-commit-packages' sender=':1.122'
Remove: linux-modules-extra-6.8.0-31-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-31.31), linux-modules-6.8.0-31-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-31.31), linux-image-6.8.0-31-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-31.31), linux-headers-6.8.0-31-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-31.31), linux-tools-6.8.0-31:amd64 (6.8.0-31.31), linux-headers-6.8.0-31:amd64 (6.8.0-31.31), linux-tools-6.8.0-31-generic:amd64 (6.8.0-31.31)
End-Date: 2024-06-26 10:32:12

Start-Date: 2024-06-26 10:33:41
Commandline: apt upgrade pipewire-audio
Requested-By: pavlov (1000)
Upgrade: pipewire-audio:amd64 (1.0.5-1, 1.0.5-1ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2024-06-26 10:33:41

Start-Date: 2024-06-26 11:04:38
Commandline: apt upgrade
Requested-By: pavlov (1000)
Upgrade: libcjson1:amd64 (1.7.17-1, 1.7.17-1ubuntu0.1~esm2), libpostproc57:amd64 (7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5, 7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5+esm1), libavcodec60:amd64 (7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5, 7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5+esm1), libavutil58:amd64 (7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5, 7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5+esm1), libswscale7:amd64 (7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5, 7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5+esm1), libswresample4:amd64 (7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5, 7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5+esm1), libavformat60:amd64 (7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5, 7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5+esm1), libavfilter9:amd64 (7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5, 7:6.1.1-3ubuntu5+esm1)
End-Date: 2024-06-26 11:04:40

Start-Date: 2024-06-26 11:05:49
Commandline: apt upgrade libpipewire-0.3-common
Requested-By: pavlov (1000)
Upgrade: libpipewire-0.3-common:amd64 (1.0.5-1, 1.0.5-1ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2024-06-26 11:05:50

Start-Date: 2024-06-26 11:11:08
Commandline: apt install libpipewire-0.3-0t64
Requested-By: pavlov (1000)
Upgrade: pipewire-pulse:amd64 (1.0.5-1, 1.0.5-1ubuntu1), pipewire:amd64 (1.0.5-1, 1.0.5-1ubuntu1), libspa-0.2-bluetooth:amd64 (1.0.5-1, 1.0.5-1ubuntu1), gstreamer1.0-pipewire:amd64 (1.0.5-1, 1.0.5-1ubuntu1), pipewire-bin:amd64 (1.0.5-1, 1.0.5-1ubuntu1), libspa-0.2-modules:amd64 (1.0.5-1, 1.0.5-1ubuntu1), libpipewire-0.3-0t64:amd64
02:52 pm
(1.0.5-1, 1.0.5-1ubuntu1), libpipewire-0.3-modules:amd64 (1.0.5-1, 1.0.5-1ubuntu1), pipewire-alsa:amd64 (1.0.5-1, 1.0.5-1ubuntu1)
End-Date: 2024-06-26 11:11:12
]

**Wayland support answer:** "*Thank you for the report, but your issue does not look like it would belong here. Sorry.
This repository is for the Wayland protocol specification and the low-level C library that deals with the protocol.
This issue here is a bug not with the protocol itself but with either
your compositor or desktop environment's implementation of the Wayland protocol and surrounding functionality,
the individual application that triggers this issue, or
the kernel driver used by your hardware
Please file the issue against your compositor/desktop environment, the application or the kernel drivers instead, whichever seems more likely to you. If you are not sure, file an issue against the application.

No dragging the window:

Dragging the window:

No cursor lagging or teleportation in this state:


Your question implies some custom theme or cursor is in use? If this is correct please edit the question and add that info.

I'm using just gnome tweaks, with the custom cursor. Changing it to default and disabling all the extensions doesn't fix the problem. So it is unlikely that cursor itself has something to do with it. I just pointed out on mozilla thing because it might be helpful for debugging. Of course nothing of that was the case before the update.

Update:
I turned off laptops built in display and the problem just vanished for a couple minutes. Hopefully it will help gain some clue for anybody who will answer. Also mirror mode fixes it. I'm like dealing with some system 'lazyness' idk in term of updating the cursor moving. All the UI elements when I control my system using the buttons are just fine, except the mouse cursor, it just lags and stutters...

Nvidia driver issue, delete it and wait for the fix.
